# creating apk using Kivy showing some error

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, pyjnius

When after I give the command:

**buildozer android debug deploy run**

I am getting the following error. Its showing syntax error ?

```
# Install distribute
# Run 'curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | venv/bin/python'
# Cwd /root/Bt/.buildozer
% Total     % Received  % Xferd   Average  Speed    Time    Time     Time  Current 
Dload Upload  Total Spent    Left Speed
100  1395  100  1395    0     0    276      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--   276
File "<stdin>", line 1
<HTML><HEAD>
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
# Command failed: curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | venv/bin
/python
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this curl failed for some reason. Could you make sure your buildozer is fully up to date with git, delete your `.buildozer` directory, and try again?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to update your Python version, make sure it is the latest.

Comment: I tried it, but didn't help
$ python -V
Python 3.8.0

Comment: I would try _inclement's_ post below.

Comment: Or try [this](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1017)!

Comment: now it ends with [this](https://pastebin.com/cq89izNd) error

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/760) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963080/kivy-buildozer-spec-error-trying-to-build-an-android-app-that-sends-an-email-o).

Comment: I couldn't downgrade buildozer, so I would try this option `option 2) do the download by hand per codingsett's comment, but make sure you have the version that buildozer expects. In my case it wants r9c. So download http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2, and unzip it into the expected location, in this case ~/.buildozer/android/platform then run buildozer again as normal.` but I need another URL. My buildozer wants this version `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86.zip` I can't find the URL for r19c-linux-x86

Comment: Check out [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads).

Comment: There is only this version `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86_64.zip` but my cpu is probably 32 bit (i686) . `file /lib/systemd/systemd
/lib/systemd/systemd: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0,...`

Comment: I tried it, but I have [this](https://pastebin.com/zzvecTZT) error now. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781916/create-kivy-apk-with-buildozer-error-aidl-cannot-be-executed) didn't help, because I don't have these directories.

Comment: I tried [this](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/532) but didn't help. Probably because my directory structure is different.

Comment: This helped: `sudo apt install aidl`

Comment: But this error occured `Building libffi for armeabi-v7a
[ERROR]:   Build failed: Couldn't find executable for CC.`

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715813/653379) but don't know what to change in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use virtual env. I had a similar issue. Just install builddozer and kivy in the default environment

Comment: Without virtual env, it doesn't work as well. See LucioRandy answer. In the comment there is where I have stuck.

Comment: I will send a video link soon in here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t2P9Wqlpa19D7z5JGQDlVLErpbvDEZHY?usp=sharing

This contains the screen recording my kivy to apk conversion

Comment: Thank you. I still have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593341/buildozer-build-failed-couldnt-find-executable-for-cc) error.

Comment: Did u install cython? And also install these dependencies. (From docs) 
`sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev`
`pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython virtualenv`  # the --user should be removed if you do this in a venv

# add the following line at the end of your ~/.bashrc file
`export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/`

Comment: Yes, I have cython 0.29.21. Now, I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468814/buildozer-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables) problem

Comment: Try installing other dependencies. Is your kivy app running fine on interpreter?

Comment: That could be the problem. The kivy app runs only in python3.6 (not python3.8). I will try to fix it.

Comment: I installed kivy from Python3.8 and the app runs, but build failed.