# Create kivy apk with buildozer ERROR: "Aidl cannot be executed"

Tags: android, python, kivy, apk, buildozer

I want to upload my kivy application to Google Play store. For that i Need an .apk file , which has an api Level of 26 or higher. The .apk that I created had an apk Level of 19. So this was my way to set the Level to 26:
I installed API 26,27,28 and the newest version of the building tool. 
In buildozer.spec i set android.api = 26.
After that I run "buildozer android release deploy run". And now I get this error:

"Check that aidl can be executed

Search for Aidl

Run 'home/dennis/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools/28.0.2/aidl' 
CWD None
Aidl cannot be executed"

What can i do to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android
2. Select *Android SDK Build-tools 26.x.x*
3. Check *aidl* file in `~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools/26.x.x/`