# Kivy buildozer.spec Error - Trying to build an android App that sends an email out

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I have an app that I'm trying to deploy and can't. Towards the beginning I get an 'ValueError: read of closed file' I don't know if this is related to openssl which is the step it's on when it crashes but if you understand this error I'd love some help. I'm not actually sure if anything is off on my buildozer.spec file as well... Thank you for your time.

Here is my buildozer.spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = TrackingMind

# (str) Package name
package.name = TrackerApp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.TrackerApp

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,json

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application vValueError:ersioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,gmail,os,time,settingjson

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.11.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Terminal OUTPUT

```
davi@davi-M11x:~/Downloads/PESS$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master b1f6064d [origin/master] Release 2019.10.06 (#1998)
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/davi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/davi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19b
# Android NDK found at /home/davi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=TrackerApp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,gmail,os,time,settingjson --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21'
# Cwd /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 27 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/davi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b
[INFO]:    Found NDK version 19b
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Found a single valid recipe set: ['gmail', 'hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'os', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'settingjson', 'sqlite3', 'time', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2 bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name TrackerApp and requirements (python3, kivy, gmail, os, time, settingjson)
[INFO]:    Dist contains the following requirements as recipes: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules (time, gmail, os, settingjson) installed from pip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    The requirements (gmail, os, settingjson, time) were not found as recipes, they will be installed with pip.
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes 
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
[INFO]:    hostpython3 download already cached, skipping                                                                                                                                                                                      
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading libffi
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/libffi
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/libffi
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/libffi/libffi/archive/8fa8837.tar.gz
[INFO]:    libffi download already cached, skipping                                                                                                                                                                                           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading openssl
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/openssl
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/openssl
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> running rm openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading openssl from https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1196, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 671, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 155, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 209, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 558, in build_recipes
    recipe.download_if_necessary()
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 356, in download_if_necessary
    self.download()
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 402, in download
    self.download_file(self.versioned_url, filename)
  File "/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 217, in download_file
    urlretrieve(url, target, report_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1819, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 624, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: read of closed file
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=TrackerApp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,gmail,os,time,settingjson --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/davi/Downloads/PESS/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     PANTHEON_TERMINAL_ID = '2'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE = 'adwaita'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/davi/Downloads'
#     GTK_CSD = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '2542'
#     GTK3_MODULES = 'pantheon-filechooser-module'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/davi'
#     USER = 'davi'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'pantheon'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'gtk3'
#     PWD = '/home/davi/Downloads/PESS'
#     HOME = '/home/davi'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1909'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/gnome:/usr/share/pantheon:/home/davi/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR = '/home/davi/data'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'pantheon'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Pantheon'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/usr/share/applications/io.elementary.terminal.desktop'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     PROMPT_COMMAND = ('__bp_precmd_invoke_cmd; dbus-send --type=method_call --session '
 '--dest=io.elementary.terminal /io/elementary/terminal '
 'io.elementary.terminal.ProcessFinished string:$PANTHEON_TERMINAL_ID '
 'string:"$(history 1 | cut -c 8-)" int32:$__bp_last_ret_value >/dev/null '
 '2>&1; __bp_interactive_mode;')
#     GDMSESSION = 'pantheon'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'davi'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/davi/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-pantheon:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/davi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/davi-M11x:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1793,unix/davi-M11x:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1793'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/davi/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/davi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/davi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Here are my system spec:

```
neofetch
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            davi@davi-M11x 
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee         -------------- 
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee       OS: elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera x86_64 
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee     Host: X570 I AORUS PRO WIFI -CF 
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee    Kernel: 5.3.0-45-generic 
eee    eee            eee       eee   Uptime: 6 hours, 35 mins 
eee   eee            eee        eee   Packages: 1834 
ee    eee           eeee       eeee   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee   Resolution: 900x1440, 1920x1200, 1920x1080 
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee   DE: Pantheon 
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee   WM: Mutter(Gala) 
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee   Theme: Elementary [GTK3] 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee    Icons: Elementary [GTK3] 
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee     Terminal: io.elementary.t 
    eeeee                 eeeee       CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6- (12) @ 3.600GHz 
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti 
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            Memory: 3120MiB / 32126MiB 

                                              neofetch
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            davi@davi-M11x 
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee         -------------- 
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee       OS: elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera x86_64 
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee     Host: X570 I AORUS PRO WIFI -CF 
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee    Kernel: 5.3.0-45-generic 
eee    eee            eee       eee   Uptime: 6 hours, 35 mins 
eee   eee            eee        eee   Packages: 1834 
ee    eee           eeee       eeee   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee   Resolution: 900x1440, 1920x1200, 1920x1080 
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee   DE: Pantheon 
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee   WM: Mutter(Gala) 
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee   Theme: Elementary [GTK3] 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee    Icons: Elementary [GTK3] 
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee     Terminal: io.elementary.t 
    eeeee                 eeeee       CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6- (12) @ 3.600GHz 
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti 
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            Memory: 3120MiB / 32126MiB
```

Comment: are you using `requests` library ?

Comment: I am not, just what I added to the spec file.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this issue on github a while ago. Here's the link
https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/760

One of the people mentioned to download the NDK manually and setting it to the `.buildozer/android/platform/` directory

However, when I got the error few weeks ago, I just deleted the .Buildozer directory from my project folder and built the apk again

Comment: Yes, I actually followed that post two days ago trying to diagnose a slightly different error. I had it crash at during the NDK download step with the VakueError: read of closed file. Following that post helped,

Comment: But I'm not sure if it's the same, cause error actually gets past the NDK step. The NDK is downloaded and implement fine, it crashed during the openssl... Idk, why I'm getting two different issues. Sucks, I built my app over so many months now it's almost impossible to get it working as an App.